# pyserum place order unknow instruction error

Tags: python, solana

I'm trying to convert SOL to USDT using pyserum.
Here's the code I'm using.

```
import base58
from pyserum.connection import conn
from pyserum.enums import OrderType, Side
from pyserum.market import Market
from pyserum.connection import get_live_markets, get_token_mints
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from spl.token.client import Token
from spl.token.constants import TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
from config import PRIVATEKEYPHANTOM

all_mint_address = get_token_mints()
all_market_address = get_live_markets()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from_coin = 'SOL'
    to_coin = 'USDT'
    symbol = f"{from_coin}/{to_coin}"
    market_address = fetch_market_address(symbol)
    mint_address = fetch_mint_address(symbol)
    
    sender_key_pair = get_keypair(PRIVATEKEYPHANTOM)
    payer = Keypair(sender_key_pair[:32])
    
    cc = conn("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

    quote_token = Token(
        cc,
        pubkey=PublicKey(mint_address), # mint address of token USDT
        program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        payer=payer,
    )


    quote_wallet = quote_token.create_account(
    payer.public_key,
    skip_confirmation=True)  # Make sure you send tokens to this address
    print("quote wallet: ", str(quote_wallet))


    market_address = PublicKey(market_address) # Address for SOL/USDT
    print(market_address)
    market = Market.load(cc, market_address)

    tx_sig = market.place_order(
        payer=quote_wallet,
        owner=payer,
        side=Side.BUY,
        order_type=OrderType.LIMIT,
        limit_price=0.01,
        max_quantity=1,
        opts = TxOpts(skip_preflight=True)
    )
    print(tx_sig)
```

Although, I receive the following error after execution.
**
Transaction failed: Error processing Instruction 1: Unknown instruction error
**

Full error can be found [here](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/CbCRgD8JQ1rhBRVM6rxPXUM9g8cF3bLctomaxogW8EFWjaVEsAXtQUfZ6KKNwe71RRfGEzrupiSr4mcJzowfuyu)

Comment: I get the same error. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm having other errors in my code when placing the order. Could you share how your `fetch_mint_address()` function works?

Comment: @Jimmy `fetch_mint_address()` is basically used to fetch the mint address for the transaction. Here's an example of it
https://pastebin.pl/view/ae317ae1

Comment: hi do you have some pyserum examples? there are none on official github

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same error and finally I found that's a good idea to replicate the order at some Serum based UI. I used https://dex.raydium.io and when I tried to replicate the error I've got

> Price must be an increment of 0.1

For SOL/USDC at least, there is a rule that I need to trade at least amount of 0.1.
I don't know why this limitation is set at DEX and why pyserum does not show some more readable error but at least changing from 0.01 to 0.1 helped me.